# How to Jump Back and forth in if/else block in mongoose function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, mongoose, promise

How to Jump Back and forth in if/else block in mongoose function?
I mean when my users already exist, then check if block, and if my users do not exist in db go to else block and save users and then come back to the if block, I don't want to copy and paste if block to else block after saving users

**Code:**

```
User.findById(msg.chat.id)
  .then((doc) => {
    if (doc) {
      console.log(doc.name);  // to here
    } else {
      console.log('Empty');  //jump from here
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Just put the common part out of the `if/else` block.

Comment: Can you edit with my example? , I mean I want to save users in else block and come back to if

Comment: Well, that's a completely different question. I suggest you edit your example as both me and @FirasOmrane undestood something else.

Comment: You should *really* edit your code example, because it is very confusing and doesn't help at all with the actual question you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this!!

When using a callback we guarantee that the document is saved when we are using it.

The callback used with the method save receives [three parameters](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save).

```
  function workAfterSaving(result) {
    console.log(result.tok);
  }

  User.findById(msg.chat.id)
    .then((doc) => {
      if (!doc) {
        // we will add the user
        kitty.save()
          .then((obj) => {
            workAfterSaving(obj);
          }).catch((err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          });
        return;
      }

      // here we will use the same function with the found user.
      workAfterSaving(doc);
    }).catch((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Upon reading OP's comment, I think they  actually want to re-run `findById` after something has been done in the `else` block, which is actually not doing just that `console.log` thing.

Comment: I mean when my users are  already exist, that check if block, and if my users thereisn't in db goto else block and save users and then come back to if, i don't want to copy and paste if block to else block after saving users

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei I modified it to fit your request

Comment: `//here you can code what you want to do with every user` they have to `findById` again, which your example doesn't explain how to do and is the whole point of the question.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think he does not want to `fundById` again he just want to add the user if he does not exist and do the remaining work with every user.

Comment: @FirasOmrane good for them if this answers the question, but I predict that OP will soon ask another question about how to avoid repeating that same chain of promises inside itself :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes I think that this helped him.

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei I modified the code so that it is more developed and explained. You are welcome.

Comment: Appreciate it, I added a Final Edit